# Applying NSFontAttributeName and NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName at the same NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, nsattributedstring, uifont

I want to apply `NSFontAttributeName` as well as `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` to a `NSMutableAttributedString`. Below is my code but its not working. It only applies the font attribute. If I remove the font attribute, it applies the underline attribute. I do not know how to apply both.

```
        let font = UIFont(name: "MyriadPro-Semibold", size: 30)
        let underlineAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Menu")
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, underlineAttributedString.length)

        underlineAttributedString.beginEditing()

        underlineAttributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font!, range: range)
        underlineAttributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: range)

        underlineAttributedString.endEditing()

        menuLabel_.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
        menuLabel_.textAlignment = .Center
        menuLabel_.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
```

Comment: This is the correct way to use `NSMutableAttributedString`. Have you tried a different font?

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was because font size was bigger than the bounding box of UILabel and it was getting cut from below.